# Error al procesar una imagen con intervention/image - PHP on Google Cloud

Tags: php, php7, imagen, google-api, google-cloud-platform

Tengo un problema cuando trato de escalar una imagen existente.

Localmente trabaja bien, solamente modifiqué el límite de memoria con:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Dado que mi memoria se agotaba.

Después le doy resize dado un patrón de repetición que necesito:

```
$img->resize($canvas_width / $repeating_pattern, null, function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
```

A continuación creo un canvas en blanco con un width que siempre está definido a 5291 y una altura obtenida de la imagen original escalada:

```
$canvas = Image::canvas($canvas_width, $img->height());
```

Al final, inserto la misma imagen en el canvas tantas veces como se requiera (mínimo 1 máximo 10)

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $repeating_pattern; $i++) {
        $canvas->insert($img, 'top-left', ($img->width() - 1) * $i, 0);
    }
```

Ejecutado con un patrón de repetición a 1 es cuando salen los siguientes errores, creo que por el escalamiento que es cuando escala la imagen para todo el canvas. A partir del patrón de repetición definido a 2, genera todo bien, el problema está cuando el patrón es de 1.

Obtengo los siguientes errores:

1. 502 Bad Gateway nginx
2. Error: Server Error The server encountered an error and could not complete your request. Please try again in 30 seconds

Se obtienen de manera aleatoria, a veces uno, a veces otro y a veces sí funciona.

Los demás patrones de repetición sí funcionan, solo el de 1 falla a veces

Lo estoy intentando con una imagen que pesa 5.66 MB

Comment: Ya intentaste un exponential backoff?

Comment: Lo investigué un poco, pero no me quedó claro cómo implementarlo, no hay mucha documentación sobre eso. Crees que me puedas ayudar un poco más?

Comment: Aquí explico como hacerlo https://stackoverflow.com/a/41105036/5983596. Está en inglés pero quizá viendo el código entiendas el concepto.